# How to reorder a binary matrix such that at least '1' value in the column

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a binary matrix A as

```
A=[0 0 0 1
   0 1 1 0;
   0 1 0 1;
   0 0 0 1;
   0 1 1 1]
```

I want to reorder the matrix A such that at least 1 column has '1' values. So, the matrix A will be come

```
%% switch first col and last col in the first row
A=[1 0 0 0
   0 1 1 0;
   0 1 0 1;
   0 0 0 1;
   0 1 1 1]
```

Now, A is satified the above condition. Is it possible to implement it in MATLAB? Thank all

Second example

```
A=[1 0 0 1;
   0 0 1 1;
   0 0 0 1]
```

Then result is

```
A=[1 0 0 1;
   0 1 1 0;  %% second and fourth col is switched
   0 0 0 1]
```

**Update**: what is happen if the row of A is comming on fly. It means that at t=0, the first row comes and A=[1 0 0 1]. Then next time, the second row comes. The matrix A will be A=[1 0 0 1; 0 0 1 1]. Then the algorithm will be check here because the second col. of A is zero. Performs switching and then next col of A comes, so on. Could you design help me the implementation for that task?

Comment: ordering is only done in cols?

Comment: Yes. It must be has 1 value in each col.

Comment: Let me clarify. What are the allowed operations for ordering

Comment: I think it just switch operation. That means switch between col or a row to make each col of A has at least 1 value.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the edit?

Comment: Yes. Assume that A is received matrix. Each rows will be send to receiver and receiver will construct matrix A based on received rows. Hence, it call A is created on fly. For each received rows. We will full fill and order the matrix A, so that above condition.

Comment: Then in my answer instead of `t=A...` you can set `t` to be the received row.

Comment: Yes. It is right. t=[received row 1; ...recevied row k]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple deterministic strategy, start from the top left, fill as many columns as you can with the first row, then continue with the next row and the next columns. For the remaining rows, just start over at the first column.

```
%Get rows in which ones can be found.
[~,r]=find(A.');
%Assign new column values for the ones
c=mod(0:numel(r)-1,size(A,2))+1;
B=zeros(size(A));
B(sub2ind(size(A),r(:),c(:)))=1;
```

Comment: Thank Daniel. But I think 0:numel(c) must be 0:numel(r). I think you typo that line. And please see my update question about the col. of A on fly

Comment: You are right, originally hat `[c,r]=find(A.');` in my code but removed it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would do (at least for tall matrices)

```
for ind = 1:min(size(A))
    t = A(ind,:);
    A(ind,:) = circshift(t,[0 -(find(t)-ind)]);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the dumbest way to do this :D

```
A=[0 0 0 1
   0 1 1 0;
   0 1 0 1;
   0 0 0 1;
   0 1 1 1];
while ~(any(A(:,1)) && any(A(:,2)) && any(A(:,3)) && any(A(:,4)))
    for ii = 1:length(A(:,1))
        A(ii,:) = A(ii,randperm(4,4));
    end
end
disp(A)
```

The code checks each column in `A` to have `1`. If not, it randomly shifts rows in `A` and repeats until the requirement is satisfied.